# Angular with Bootstrap - To load html file in divs like load() jquery function

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new in Angular, and i am testing my first example. In my index.html, i have the next code html:

```
<div id="customer-information" class="col-md-12"><!-- header maxi --></div>
<div id="customerinformation-collapse" class="col-md-12 collapse out"><!-- header mini --></div>
```

The example combines angularjs with bootstrap 3.

I want to load a html file in the div with id="customer-information" and other html file in the div with id="customerinformation-collapse".

How could make this with angular?

After, I will control the collapsed div from the html file with id="customer-information" using bootstrap with:

```
<span class="btn-collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#customerinformation-collapse"></span>
```

I am looking the next URL:
http://www.journaldev.com/6225/angular-js-routing-and-multiple-views-tutorial-example#comment-33749

Can i combine angular js with bootstrap js? with bootstrap css i know that yes

Thanks,

Comment: you can use ng-include

Comment: Or if you're going to reuse the HTML in several places in your site, consider creating a custom directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive (the "Creating Directives" section)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-view

```
<div ui-view="menu"></div>
<div ui-view="content"></div>



$stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
      url: "/dashboard",
      views: {
        "menu": { templateUrl: "menuLeft.tpl.html" },
        "content": { templateUrl : "dashboard.tpl.html" }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom directive (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and link your HTML you wish to include as the "template".